# Rename Jsonproperties from third party jar using previous version of json

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I have a REST interface that returns an object.  One of the fields in that object is an object from a third party jar.   The third party jar object contains fields marked `@JsonProperty` from Jackson 1+.    We are using Jackson 2+ and these annotations aren't being picked up.

I tried creating a MixIn, but I'm still not getting the correct property names.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class ThirdPartyObject {
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    public String ln;

    ...
}
```

---

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public interface NewObject {
   @JsonProperty("lastName")
   abstract String getLastName();
}
```

In my test, `objectMapper` is initialized with:

```
objectMapper.setMixIns(ImmutableMap.<Class<?>, Class<?>>of(ThirdPartyObject.class, NewObject.class));
```

It is returning `{"ln": "Smith"}`
when I'm expecting `{"lastName": "Smith"}`